# How to add a column to a dataframe with a list of row numbers?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and want to add a new column of bool values, referring to a list of row numbers.

```
>>> df
    col1  col2
0     1     1
1     2     2
2     4     3
3     8     4

>>> lst_rowNumbers
[1, 3]
```

The result will look like this:

```
    col1  col2   bool
0     1     1  False
1     2     2   True
2     4     3  False
3     8     4   True
```

I thought this would work, but it doens't.

```
>>> df['bool'] = False
>>> df.iloc[ lst_rowNumbers ]['bool'] = True
```

How can I do with with Pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If want select by index names:

```
df['bool'] = False
df.loc[ lst_rowNumbers , 'bool'] = True
```

Or:

```
df['bool'] = df.index.isin(lst_rowNumbers)
```

---

```
print (df)
   col1  col2   bool
0     1     1  False
1     2     2   True
2     4     3  False
3     8     4   True
```

If want select by positions is necessary get position of column name by [`Index.get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html):

```
print (df)
   col1  col2
a     1     1
b     2     2
c     4     3
d     8     4

lst_rowNumbers = [1,3]
df['bool'] = False
df.iloc[ lst_rowNumbers , df.columns.get_loc('bool')] = True
```

Or use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.isin.html) with real index values returned by indexing:

```
df['bool'] = df.index.isin(df.index[lst_rowNumbers])
```

---

```
print (df)
   col1  col2   bool
a     1     1  False
b     2     2   True
c     4     3  False
d     8     4   True
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! ```df.iloc[ lst_rowNumbers , df.columns.get_loc('bool')] = True``` is what I was looking for!